# Can you hand me that xxx(phrase)

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Let's say you are cooking together with spouse, then while your battering eggs, you ask your spouse to **get the frying pan and give it to you** can you say:

> "Can you **hand me** that frying pan please"(get the pan ang give it you)

Am I correct to say this according to what I really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe.**  *Hand me that ____* implies particularly the act of giving it to you by hand, and as a native US English speaker I would only use it if the person already had it in their hand or if it were very nearby (i.e. it was "to hand").

For example, if the pan were sitting on the counter right in front of my spouse, but she were not actually holding it, I would probably still say "Hand me that pan."  But if it were in another room, *hand* would sound inappropriate.  I don't think there is a strict rule for how far away something is, but I might say "Hand me two eggs" even if they were in the refrigerator, but not "Hand me the colander" if it were in a cabinet in another room.

Comment: Yes that's it! If it is very near/actually holding it, you could say **"hand me that''**. I have just learned another new phrase here, thx very much.

Answer (score 1):

No!

In *this context* get me means **both** she taking it and giving to you. So, without messing up an already-good phrase, let's say...

> Can you get me a frying pan?

Comment: This is also a valid answer, but, on a hunch, there is something missing in your answer. Using **’'get''** is correct, however I wanted to change it into a less awkward way and making it sound more casual by the use of **''hand me that''** phrase.